# Org export to Stack Exchange

Tags: org-mode, org-export

How to export org-mode text as Stack Exchange's formatted text?

For instance having `/Xizzy/` being exported to `_Xizzy_` (“Xizzy” between “_”), while exporting equation in latex syntax.

I would rather avoid using HTML.

Answer (score 3):

The org markdown exporter translates `/emphasized/` to `*emphasized*`, which is valid markup for Stackexchange.

However,the markdown exporter isn't enabled by default. To enable it, you need to add `md` to the variable `org-export-backends`. This needs to happen at the correct time in your startup, so it may be easiest to do this via the `customize-variable` interface. i.e., `M-x customize-variable org-export-backends`.

Comment: It seems that it improperly export other things, such as equations though.

Comment: Equations aren't supported by markdown, and are inconsistently supported on the stack exchange network, so I'm not sure there is a single "correct" way to export them